# Client ID is not getting generated for asp.net controls

Tags: asp.net, .net

I am writing a simple webform on .net 4.0 framework.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
        <span>Name</span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtName"   runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>Email</span>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" EnableViewState="false" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Issue is when the form renders on browser, I am not getting ClientID for the server side controls. This is strange for me.
The portion of the markup in the browser is

```
 <div>
        <input type="submit" name="btnButton" value="Submit" id="btnButton" />
    </div>
```

Notice there is no clientID.

**Edit :**  Client ID something like 'ctl00$MasterPageBody$ctl00$btnButton2'

Comment: value of Id attribute of generated markup is a client id.

Comment: Client IDs like that aren't needed as much in ASP.NET version 4.0, thankfully. When working with simpler document structures, the client IDs will be much simpler. Just trust what it's telling you.

Comment: I guess its not an invalid question. I wasn't aware of the fact that now .net 4.0 framework has CliendIdMode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ClientID` is a *server side* attribute.

You would see the `ClientID` on the client as the `ID` attribute:

```
id="btnButton"
```

Comment: something like 'ctl00$MasterPageBody$ctl00$btnButton2'

Comment: @vaibhav - There is no guarantee by the framework that it will produce that kind of `id`.

Comment: I am trying to write some javascript based on these id. How will I be sure that what kind of ID the framework will generate.

Comment: Use `<%:control.ClientId%>`. It will generate the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The client id of the button is btnButton. The other one "ctl..." is when you have your control inside a masterpage.  As a side not: If you don´t wan´t asp.net changing your id:s you can set clientidmode='static'.

Answer (score 0):

Client id is calculated on the server, it never gets sent to the client.

Comment: yes I know, the page markup is getting generated from the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need runat="server" to generate a client ID for the control for the reasons mentioned

Comment: in your example above there is no runat=server on your input control.